# where can I find Slider Syncing(asNavFor) styleSheet (react-slick)

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

I'm creating a carousel that similar to [Slider Syncing](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/as-nav-for) design.
then, I want to refer to design styleSheet.
(in particular, the margin between slider.)

I searched the styleSheet file in [repository](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick), but I can't find it.

Do you know where the stylesheet is?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try including the `css` outlined in the [documentation](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick#documentation) of the repo?

Comment: @Peppermintology

Thanks comment. I added two css files .

`
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
`